# Cannot enable checkbox in android ListView using server data

Tags: android, json, android-listview, android-checkbox

I am getting data from a server in json format and passing it through a LazyAdapter in a ListView. I want when the tododone data from the server is true to enable the checkbox in the list. I have the code above for enabling the checkbox but does not work.

```
    TextView todoid = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.todoid); // id
    TextView todotile = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.todotitle); // title
    CheckBox check = (CheckBox)vi.findViewById(R.id.check); // checkbox

    String test;
    HashMap<String, String> todo = new HashMap<String, String>();
    todo = data.get(position);

    // Setting all values in listview
    todoid.setText(todo.get(TodoFragment.TAG_TODOID));
    todotile.setText(todo.get(TodoFragment.TAG_TODOTITLE));
    test=(todo.get(TodoFragment.TAG_TODODONE));

    if (test.toString()=="true") {
            check.setChecked(true);
    }
    return vi;
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use:
`"true".equals(test.toString())"`
instead of `test.toString()=="true"`

**UPD:**
The same sense, but more clear:
`if (Boolean.parseBoolean(test))`

PS: I don't know, why you use: `test.toString()` if `test` is already a String.

Hope it helps